# jQuery UI Autocomplete - _renderItem not firing on first paste

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to get a custom rendered autocomplete label to populate when an input is pasted in. Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/sq5xyLas/

To test, copy `jQuery` to clipboard, and then paste it in the input textbox. Nothing happens. Remove that entry and paste it again, and the search fires. Why does the `.autocomplete("instance")._renderItem` not fire on the first paste?

```
var projects = [{
  value: "jquery",
  label: "jQuery",
  desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
  icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
}, {
  value: "jquery-ui",
  label: "jQuery UI",
  desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
  icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
}, {
  value: "sizzlejs",
  label: "Sizzle JS",
  desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
  icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png"
}];

$(input).autocomplete({
  delay: 200,
  minLength: 3,
  source: projects,
}).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, resultItem) {
  console.log("A paste event has happened")
  return $("<li>")
    .append("<div class='autocomplete-item'><div class='autocomplete-img-container'></div><div> " + resultItem.label + "</div></div>")
      .appendTo(ul);
  };
}
</script>
<textarea id="textarea" class="small-input" placeholder="Add a item"  onkeyup="showResult(this)"></textarea>
```

**Update**

Updated source to

```
     source: function(request, response) {    
        //Do some AJAX
    }
```

however the `_renderItem` was still not firing.

Adding:

```
  if(dynamicSource){
        response( dynamicSource);
    } 
    else{
        response({});
    }
```

Solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var projects = [{
  value: "jquery",
  label: "jQuery",
  desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
  icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
}, {
  value: "jquery-ui",
  label: "jQuery UI",
  desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
  icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
}, {
  value: "sizzlejs",
  label: "Sizzle JS",
  desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
  icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png"
}]
$('#textarea').autocomplete({
  minLength: 3,
  source: projects,
}).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, resultItem) {
  console.log("A paste event has happened")
  return $("<li>")
    .append("<div class='autocomplete-item'><div class='autocomplete-img-container'></div><div> " + resultItem.label + "</div></div>")
    .appendTo(ul);
};
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<textarea id="textarea" class="small-input" placeholder="Add a item"></textarea>
```

You no need to create instance of autocomplete all the time a keyup happen.

Comment: Ended up refactoring to this method. I had an issue with dynamic autocomplete source. Updated question.

Comment: sir can you elaborate more on this?